# PHP mailer returning Fatal Error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have been working on my first PHP contact form.
I have also been running into some problems. I have gotten the files to all talk to each other, and it has gotten to the point where it looks like it is going to work. But, after you input the information in the form, press send, it comes back with this error:


*Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/content/12/11666412/html/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 594




Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused) in /home/content/12/11666412/html/phpMailer/class.smtp.php on line 122
Thank you!*


So, I assume 2 things:

1: I should try using a different port # for connecting to google (587 has worked for me in the past on a different server, is this something that sometimes changes?). What port number should I be using?

2: Something is wrong in the PHP mailer files (that I downloaded from the PHPmailer site). Should I try redownloading them? I doubt anything is wrong with the PHPmailer, seems to be a very reputable tool that people use, the code is too advanced for me to analyze. 


Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many results in google for this problem. Frist hit: http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-4/vbulletin-4-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/407183-smtp-problem-with-gmail  Further Informations: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en

Comment: Example for using phpmailer with gmail: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail  Is everything configured correct?

Comment: @MichaelWalter - Seems that my port# is correct according to google, and $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; is correct. Looks like it may have something to do server side. I am reading that it might have something to do with " openSSL " settings within the php.ini file... which I do not know how to get to.

Comment: @MichaelWalter I believe everything to be configured correctly with my file. I have gotten this file to work on a different server. But, the website moved to a different server, and now I cannot get it to work.

Comment: it depends on your hosting-provider, if you can change the configuration. you can check the config via calling phpinfo(); in your script. search in the result of it for something like "openssl"

Comment: Here is a link to the site, http://macnx.com/test.php ,  with that function. From everything I have looked at, it all seems to be enabled.

Comment: looks ok for me, too. maybe you have same same problem as this guy: https://drupal.org/node/900638 (comment #1). please contact your provider for informations about this topic

Comment: I was afraid of this... this is out of my element. Thanks for all the help @MichaelWalter

Comment: Well, just found out about this little gem. Godaddy blocks these ports because they want you to use their email. PHPmailer with a SMPTgmail account does not work on Godaddy. Figured you might want to know.

Comment: Yes, it was mentioned in the second comment of my last link ;)